# What order do I write algebraic math problems?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

My math teacher is a little bit picky on the order we write our simplified algebraic math problems, and I forgot to take notes on this. Let's say you have the problem $2(y + 3) - 4x$. Would I write that $2y - 4x + 6$ or $6 + 2y - 4x$?

Please help me,
-LtLobster

Comment: There will be no definite answer as they are the same so it shouldn't matter , the only answer could be what ever that teacher wants

Answer (score 0):

Ask your instructor, as it varies in form.

Technically, both are correct as the represent the expression the same in 2 forms.

I remember back in middle school that 1 teacher wanted it ordered in alphabetical order then in descending degrees, but I like I said, I don't know how your instructor wants it.

If you want to go with my method, it would be $-4x+2y+6$

Then again, negatives at the start are ugly.